# Haskell: is "list comprehension" using eager evaluation?

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension, lazy-evaluation

I just tried this:

```
Prelude> [x*2|x<-[1..10]]
[2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20]
```

Well it seems not like F#'s "seq" which is lazy evaluated. Here all the elements inside this set is printed out, so seems "list comprehension" is eager evaluation.

What if I wish to build a "lazy evaluated" one?
Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

In Haskell *everything* (well almost) is lazy and this is no difference

But if you ask GHCi to print it (you did with the input) it will evaluate all of it

To see it use this:

```
Prelude> let xs = [x*2|x<-[1..10]]
Prelude> :sprint xs
xs = _
```

the `_` indicates a *unevaluated* thunk here

---

BTW: this is why Haskell has no issue with something like this:

```
let xs = [x*2|x<-[1..]]
```

which is an infinite list - now if you ask it to print it out it will *take some time* ;)

The same is true for F#'s `seq { ... }` but not for F#'s lists!

Comment: Thanks, but I don't quite get what :sprint does, on "lazy evaluation", because:

    Prelude> let a=2
    Prelude> :sprint a
    a = _

Still seems to print "_"

Comment: `:sprint` is a [GHCi Command](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-commands.html) which "Prints a value without forcing its evaluation. :sprint is similar to :print, with the difference that unevaluated subterms are not bound to new variables, they are simply denoted by ‘_’." - so you can check what get's evaluated/forced and what not

Comment: [Here is a very good introduction](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000929/ch02.html#sec_par-eval-whnf) on this stuff ^^

Comment: @viksantata That's because `2` isn't an evaluated value in Haskell.  It's a polymorphic expression whose evaluation depends on its type.  Try something like `2 :: Int`.

Comment: @Carl right ... I totally misread the comment/question - thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 4):

You can test this yourself by asking for an infinite list:

```
Prelude> take 10 [ x*2 | x <- [1..], x `mod` 3 == 0 ]
[6,12,18,24,30,36,42,48,54,60]
```